# Sitecore fast query is not returning results from master db while Sitecore query is returning results

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7

I'm using Sitecore fast query to get results. But I'm not getting any results if I use the query in master db, I tried running it in XPath viewer as well. But I get the results for Sitecore query. The same fast query works against web database.

```
fast://#sitecore#/#content#/#Something#/#Something#/#AU#/#Website#/ancestor-or-self::*[@@templateid='{463D7680-BF52-49DF-B7D5-88E97416A1FA}']/Configuration/Navigation/Footer Bottom Right/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still really don't understand what is the cause of the issue, But cleaning up all the databases solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ancestor-or-self::` use `//*` :

```
fast://#sitecore#/#content#/#Something#/#Something#/#AU#/#Website#//*[@@templateid='{463D7680-BF52-49DF-B7D5-88E97416A1FA}']/Configuration/Navigation/Footer Bottom Right/*
```